# merge pcap files in wirehshark

Tags: bash, merge, pcap

I have created a sh script to merge pcap files using 'mergecap' command. But I'm facing an issue. What I need is merge all pcap files older that 5 days, so I use 'find' command to find all files older than 5 days

```
FILES=$(find /capture/nop/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +5)
```

How would I use array FILES in the mergecap command

```
mergecap -w outfulfile.pcap input1.pcap input2.pcap
```

And also is there anyway to use use the file name of first and last file merged as the file name of the output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=($(find /capture/nop/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +5))
# Discard path name and extension
TAG1=$(basename "${FILES[0]}" | sed 's/.pcap//')
TAG2=$(basename "${FILES[-1]}" | sed 's/.pcap//')
mergecap -w "output_from_${TAG1}_to_$TAG2" ${FILES[@]}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me what FILES[-1] does? Because it is giving a bad array subscript error. And the mergecap says no input files also..

Comment: ``FILES[-1]`` should give the last element in ``FILES``. Is it because the ``find`` command did not find any file given the conditions?

Comment: Hi can you please tell me how to remove the full path in FILES?, I just need the file name not the full path to it.

Comment: I've edited the answer for that (and fixed an error), can you please check if it works for you?

Comment: The output file name only contains the first input file's name. :(

Comment: Sorry, my bad -- due to the use of underscores, the variable before it has to be wrapped in braces. Or simply don't use ``_`` in the output filename? :)

Comment: A small correction TAG1=$(basename "${FILES[0]}" | sed 's/.pcap//')

Comment: while running this in crontab , the output files is not created, is there some way to convert the FILES array say 15 by 1 array to 1 by 15 array?